# Software to write/compose music for game - for non professionals

Tags: software-rec, music

Looking for some software which will make for person without professional musical skills to write simple/nice musical themes for iPhone games. Also will appreciate any tutorial/blog describing procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fruityloops would be my suggestion. Not free, but cheaper than most. i suspect they'll be some free open source apps out there similar.

Answer (score 1):

FL Studio is OK but a lot of it is largely based on presets & built-in loops. This is useful for some but can be creatively restricting. For recording & arranging Audacity is a fantastic open-source Audio editor.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renoise#Features
for samples, can recommend you to use good 8-bit synth: http://www.google.com/search?q=vst+sid

Also, not an oobe solution, but you can look for an artist at Jamendo/any other free music community.

Answer (score 0):

Music Ace - paid software - for learning music for kids, but there is a section where you can create your own music, with several kinds of instruments and all the notes and such...excellent, works well!

http://www.harmonicvision.com/mafact.htm